# Laravel JavaScript File response for JSONP response

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4, jsonp

I'd like to generate a JavaScript file for JSONP data exchange.
All fine, but I need / want to set the header as :

```
header("Content-Type: text/javascript");
```

or

```
header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
```

Is this possible in a response from a controller in Laravel 4, or do I need to create a view and set the header with PHP?

I'd like to output something like:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"item1":"value1","item2":"value2"}');

// then do whatever with the object
 $('#somediv').html(obj.item1);
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, looks like I have to answer my question myself :-). Thanks to @terrylow for trying though.

Here is the way to change the header of my response using my function in my controller

```
public function javascriptResponse(){
    $statusCode = 200;
    $content = "var obj = JSON.parse('{\"item1\":\"value1\",\"item2\":\"value2\",\"some\":\"whoaevaNew\"}');"; 
    $response = Response::make($content, $statusCode);
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
    return $response;
}
```

variable content can also be filled with a view:

```
 $content = View::make('tools/jsonp_resonse'); // also possible with view
```

Hope that will help someone...

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method provided by laravel

```
return Response::jsonp($callback, $data,$status, $header);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I've seen that function, but I'm unable to use it, since the online documentation is (at least for me) insufficient. Could you give an example on how to get the response from my question?